# integrate POCO library in android ndk

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, poco-libraries

i am trying to develop cross platform app ( on native level ) that uses `POCO socket` library with `android NDK`. but i dont know how to integrate/use `POCO library` in `android NDK` using gradle in studio.

i am using `com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0` gradle version.
And following is my `build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.ndkproto"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName = "ndk-proto-jni"
            stl "stlport_static"
            ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'log'])
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
```

i have downloaded [POCO library](http://pocoproject.org/download/index.html) but dont know what to alter in `build.gradle` file to use its C++ function in ndk. i tried to hunt over net but couldn't find any material or official guide related to that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't tried to use POCO library, but I successfuly used non-boost asio library.
Look, what I've done.

Put asio files to directory as follows

```
java
jni
prebuilt
    asio
        1.10.6
            asio_files_and_directories
    openssl
        armeabi
            include
            lib
        x86
            include
            lib
```

Then I used `gradle-experimental plugin` and wrote `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem;

final APP_ABIS = ["x86", "armeabi"]

model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            openssl {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    if (targetPlatform.getName() == "armeabi" || targetPlatform.getName() == "x86") {
                        headers.srcDir file("src/main/prebuilt/openssl/${targetPlatform.getName()}/include")
                        sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/prebuilt/openssl/${targetPlatform.getName()}/lib/libssl_1_0_0.so")
                    }
                }
            }
            opencrypto {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    if (targetPlatform.getName() == "armeabi" || targetPlatform.getName() == "x86") {
                        headers.srcDir file("src/main/prebuilt/opencrypto/${targetPlatform.getName()}/include")
                        sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/prebuilt/openssl/${targetPlatform.getName()}/lib/libcrypto_1_0_0.so")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }

    android.sources.main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDir file("src/main/jni")
            }

            exportedHeaders {
                srcDir file("src/main/prebuilt/asio/1.10.6/include")
            }

            dependencies {
                library "openssl" linkage "shared"
                library "opencrypto" linkage "shared"
            }
        }

        jniLibs {
            dependencies {
                library "openssl"
                library "opencrypto"
           }
        }
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName "ndk_module_with_asio"

        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        cppFlags.add("-frtti")
        cppFlags.add("-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS")
        cppFlags.add("-DASIO_STANDALONE")

        abiFilters.addAll(APP_ABIS)

        ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log", "m", "z"])

        stl "gnustl_static"
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-project.txt'))
            ndk.with {
                debuggable = true
            }
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-project.txt'))
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
}
```

Also I have java files with jni functions to call my native methods and at application start I do

```
try {
    System.loadLibrary("ssl_1_0_0");
    System.loadLibrary("crypto_1_0_0");
    System.loadLibrary("ndk_module_with_asio");
}
catch( UnsatisfiedLinkError ex ) {
    System.out.println("Native.java System.loadLibrary error occured: " + ex);
}
```

As you can see I've load manually built version of openssl. But it's not necessary. I added it, cause android openssl library is old and to show how to load shared libraries with gradle.
I hope, having this example, you can load POCO library, or just use non-boost asio.

Comment: for asio did you just copy  content from `C:\Users\niharb\Downloads\asio-1.10.6\asio-1.10.6\include` to `jni\prebuilt\asio` ?

Comment: Yes. `asio_files_and_directories` - `doc`, `include`, `src` directories and all other files.

Comment: i have tried ur approach but i am getting some error `http://s33.postimg.org/7w6a85nzj/image.png` and `http://s33.postimg.org/h2y9tu1f3/image.png`

Comment: Please, check `exportedHeaders` section. Is the path the same, where your headers are? *Check twice* Do you use `gradle-experimental plugin`? Have you tried to delete all temporary gradle directories to get clean build?

Comment: see my edits , yes  i am using `gradle-experimental`

Comment: preiously i dont see any boost folder in it as it throws `boots/config.hpp No such file or directory` exist

Comment: I don't see `cppFlags.add("-DASIO_STANDALONE")` And If I were you, I'd not edit your previous `build.gradle` for POCO, but write a new one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113623/discussion-between-user1056837-and-hunt).